# ¿Por qué mi método Pila.Pop() tiene fallos en memoria?

Tags: c, pilas, nodos, pop

Tengo que implementar el método pop de una pila en C y he hecho lo siguiente:

```
Stack_pop(tStack *stack) {       
    if (stack != NULL)
    {        
        tStackNode *node = malloc(sizeof(tStackNode));
        node=stack->first->next;
        stack = node;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }    
}
```

En la teoría debería funcionar: Obtengo primero el nodo correspondiente al siguiente y seguidamente lo asigno como nodo actual. Pero cuando lo voy a probar se me queda colgado, por lo que es un error de asignación de memoria. El struct tStack es el siguiente:

```
typedef struct tNode {
    tValue e;
    struct tNode *next;
} tStackNode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```
tStackNode *node = malloc(sizeof(tStackNode));
node=stack->first->next;
stack = node;
```

Ese código tiene 3 fallas:

- Esa reserva de memoria con `malloc` es innecesaria, lo único que ocasiona es [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria).
- La expresión: `stack->first->next` dará como resultado la dirección de memoria del siguiente nodo pero después la guardas en el puntero `node`, no tiene ningún sentido hacer eso, debido a que, el puntero `node` se liberará en memoria cuando la función finalice (por lo tanto, se pierde la referencia).
- Por último, vuelves a guardar el contenido de `node`, en `stack`, es decir, en ningún momento actualizas el puntero `first` (el miembro de la estructura `tStackNode`).

Solución:

```
Stack_pop(tStack *stack) 
{      
    tStackNode* aux; 
    if (stack != NULL)
    {        
        aux = stack->first;
        stack->first = stack->first->next;
        free(aux);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }    
}
```

Como veras, necesitamos apoyarnos de un puntero auxiliar para poder liberar el último nodo y adicional a eso, actualizar el puntero/miembro `first`. Ya que debes tener en cuenta que `first` debe tener la dirección base del siguiente nodo.

Comment: Maravillosa explicación. Ando bastante perdido con la memoria dinámica y te agradezco tu ayuda tanto en esta como en las otras preguntas en las que me has ayudado.